# Alinear Checkbox

Tags: html, c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

necesito que me den una mano para alinear unos checkbox que tengo. Estuve probando varias cosas pero no logro los resultados que quiero.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.entities)
                {
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6 float-right">
                            <div>

                                @item.Name <strong>@Html.CheckBox("n[0]") @Html.Hidden("n[0]", false)</strong>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }
```

Comment: veo que usas bootstrap? por lo del col-md-6 float-right hacia donde quieres alinearlo? una imagen ayudaría a formular una buena respuesta!

Comment: El check tendria que estar ubicado a la derecha de un un nombre: nombre  (check)

Answer (score 0):

Pues creo que Colocando tu @item.Name colocandolo en otro div ya tienes que tratar de justar 3 rejillas con el md-2 float-right en una  se mostraria lo que quieres y otra de md-8

Este codigo lo hice usando solo html y boostrap pero trata de implementarlo con tu tag razor.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 float-right">
      Name o el tag @item.name
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 float-right">
      <input type="checkbox" id="NameItem" name="chkName" value="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 float-right" style="background-color:lavender;"/>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Sin embargo te sugiero revises la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/grid/) de los grid en bootstrap